# fatal alert : certificate_unknown in jmeter while recording native mobile application

Tags: jmeter

I am trying to record the native app performance testing by using jmeter HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder and after installing ApacheJMeterRootCA certificate in mobile device and also configuring Proxy settings, I am getting certificate_unknown error whenever I open the app and try to use it

Note : JDK8 and JMeter 4.0 is used

Comment: Why don't update to JMeter 5?

Comment: And could you describe how do you record requests from mobile?

Comment: Is there any android app or ios app available for recording jmeter script?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming correct JMeter configuration (i.e. you have imported JMeter's self-signed certificate onto device and the device proxy configuration matches [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder) settings) you should be able to record your application traffic normally.

Unless you're using latest Android versions ([Nougat 7](https://www.android.com/versions/nougat-7-0/) or higher) where you need to amend your application source code in order to configure the application to trust user certificates.

1. Add the next line to your [application manifest](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro) (under `application` tag)

   ```
   android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
   ```
2. Add `network_security_config.xml` file under `res` folder of your application and put the following code into it:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <network-security-config>
       <debug-overrides>
           <trust-anchors>
               <!-- Trust user added CAs while debuggable only -->
               <certificates src="user" />
           </trust-anchors>
       </debug-overrides>
   </network-security-config>
   ```
3. Rebuild your application and run it in debug mode - now JMeter should be able to capture the requests.

More information:

- [Bypassing Android’s Network Security Configuration](https://www.nccgroup.trust/uk/about-us/newsroom-and-events/blogs/2017/november/bypassing-androids-network-security-configuration/)
- [Recording Using Android Devices](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/360000285357-Recording-Using-Android-Devices)

Comment: Is there any android app or ios app available for recording jmeter script without doing these configuration?